# How to add the service for my custom media player in android

Tags: android, audio, service, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I have done my custom media player for streaming audio file from server but i don't know how to add the background service to this media player and like to add in the notification bar too from which we can control and close the audio player itself. Please tell me anyone how to make a service for custom streaming - audio player.

My Code Part :

```
public class AudioStream extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
    OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener,
    OnPreparedListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnErrorListener, OnInfoListener {

private ImageButton buttonPlayPause;
private SeekBar seekBarProgress;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private TextView totalDuration, currentDuration;
private Handler mHandler;
private int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds;
private Utils utils;
private String streamUrl, thumbImgUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_stream);

    // Getting Stream Url from the preview activity
    if(getIntent()!= null){
        streamUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("normalurl");
        thumbImgUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("thumburl");
    }
    initView();
}


/** This method initialise all the views in project */
private void initView() {

    // this handler using for update the seekbar progress and current time duration of the file
    mHandler = new Handler();
    utils = new Utils();

    buttonPlayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause);
    buttonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);

    seekBarProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBarTestPlay);
    seekBarProgress.setMax(99); // It means 100% .0-99
    seekBarProgress.setOnTouchListener(this);

    currentDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.musicCurrentLoc);
    totalDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.musicDuration);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    // start the asyntask to start the streaming and start the player
        AudioStreamingAsyntask audioAsyn = new AudioStreamingAsyntask();
        audioAsyn.execute(streamUrl);

        seekBarProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

}

/**
 * Set the URL inot Media player
 */
public void setDataSource(String url) {
        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause) {
        /**
         * ImageButton onClick event handler. Method which start/pause
         * mediaplayer playing
         */
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon_large);
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon_large);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.SeekBarTestPlay) {
        /**
         * Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer to
         * seekBar primary progress position
         */
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v;
            int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100)
                    * sb.getProgress();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
            updateProgressBar();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    /**
     * MediaPlayer onCompletion event handler. Method which calls then song
     * playing is complete
     */
    buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon_large);
}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    /**
     * Method which updates the SeekBar secondary progress by current song
     * loading from URL position
     */
    seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    //primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
    updateProgressBar();
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon_large);
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon_large);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    //mHandler = null;
}

/**
 * Update timer on seekbar
 * */
public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000);
}

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long mtotalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        long mcurrentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        // Displaying time completed playing            
        currentDuration.setText(""
                + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(mcurrentDuration));

        // Displaying Total Duration time
        totalDuration.setText(""
                + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(mtotalDuration));

        // Updating progress bar
        int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(mcurrentDuration,
                mtotalDuration));
        // Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
        seekBarProgress.setProgress(progress);

        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int position, boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        mediaPlayer.start();

    long mcurrentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    //position = utils.progressToTimer(seekbar.getProgress(), totalDuration);
    currentDuration.setText(""
            + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(mcurrentDuration));
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(),
            totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //sb.append("Media Player Error: ");
        switch (what) {
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
            sb.append("Not Valid for Progressive Playback");                        
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
            sb.append("Server Died");                       
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
            sb.append("Media Error Unknown");                       
            break;
        default:
            sb.append(" Non standard (");
            sb.append(what);
            sb.append(")");
        }
        //sb.append(" (" + what + ") ");
        if(extra == -1004)
            sb.append("Network interruption occured : "+extra);
        else if(extra == -110)
            sb.append("Media Player Error : "+extra);
        else
            sb.append("Unknown Media Player Error");
        //sb.append(extra);
        PreviewActivity.backClick = false;
        showErrorDialog("Cannot play Audio", sb.toString());
        return true;


}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
void showErrorDialog(String title, String message) {
    try{
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

        // Setting Background color to Dialog
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed

                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });


        // Showing Alert Message
        if(this!= null && !this.isFinishing()){
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException Iae)
    {
        Iae.printStackTrace();
    }

}

// handle the info and warning of the media player
@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //sb.append("Media Player Error: ");
    if(Constants.DEBUG)Log.d("AudioStream", "Info : "+what+" "+extra);
    switch (what) {
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
        sb.append("Not Valid for Progressive Playback");                        
        break;
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
        sb.append("Server Died");                       
        break;
    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
        sb.append("Media Error Unknown");                       
        break;
    default:
        sb.append(" Non standard (");
        sb.append(what);
        sb.append(")");
    }
    //sb.append(" (" + what + ") ");
    if(extra == -1004)
        sb.append("Network interruption occured : "+extra);
    else if(extra == -110)
        sb.append("Media Player Error : "+extra);
    else
        sb.append("Unknown Media Player Error");
    //sb.append(extra);
    PreviewActivity.backClick = false;
    showErrorDialog("Cannot play Audio", sb.toString());
    return true;
}

class AudioStreamingAsyntask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Result> {

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AudioStream.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        if(mProgressDialog != null)
            mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = params[0];
        setDataSource(url);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mProgressDialog = null;
    }

}
```

}

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Go to [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) for best explanation

Comment: Thank for your comment, could u please give some example code depends on my code

Comment: all the required code snippet available in that link.

Comment: i don't know how to integrate those code into my code part, i getting some difficulties while integrating.So please bring some example or tutorials depends upon my code that would be helpful